# How to generate a random point on an elliptic curve without knowing it's corresponding scalar private key

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, provable-security, secret-sharing, elliptic-curve-generation

Given an elliptic curve with generator $G$, is it possible to generate a random point on the curve $Q = a \cdot G$ **without** knowing the secret value $a$ that generated it? Note that just using an $a$ to generate $Q$, and then "throwing away" $a$ (forgetting about it) isn't a valid solution. Also note that $Q$ should be uniformly distributed over all valid values (i.e. as if $a$ was chosen uniformly between 0 and $n-1$).

A toy application I have is about making some "fake" Diffie–Hellman secret exchanges, where 1 party can't get to the secret because they don't know their key $a$ (and weren't just be trusted to "throw away" the value of $a$ after generating $Q$). This is all to ultimately enable "playing poker over the phone".

Comment: Like this one [Generating a random point on an elliptic curve over a finite field](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68603/18298)? 2. method.

Comment: Will that method yield $Q$'s that are uniform over the the valid $Q$'s that would be generated as $a\cdot G$? Also, will that method be inefficient, in particular, because of rejecting invalid $x$'s?

Comment: Since there are multiple parties involved, you can have the first party generate a random $U$ (it won't matter how it's generated). The second party multiplies $U$ by a random value and returns $Q$ = $[b]U$. Neither party knows what to multiply $G$ by to get $Q$.

Comment: Yes, it will be uniform. Yes, SageMath already uses this. The theory is the number of points and the number of possible coordinates.

Comment: Aman, that solves my problem, thanks! I can't believe I didn't think of something so simple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating a random point on an elliptic curve over a finite field](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68601/generating-a-random-point-on-an-elliptic-curve-over-a-finite-field)

Comment: @AmanGrewal Your solution needs to assume that the second party is an honest actor or that they provide a zero-knowledge proof that they know $b$. Otherwise they could simply ignore $U$ and return a value of their choice.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a random $x$ value. Calculate $y^2 = x^3+ax+b \bmod p$. Then try to form $y$ by taking the square root $\bmod p$. If the square root fails then no $(x,y)$ pair exists on the curve. If the square root works, flip a coin; if tails form $y = p-y \bmod p$.

This is how public key compression works. Only the low bit of y is saved. Form $y^2$, take the square root (which had better work). If the low bit of $y$ is wrong then form $y = p-y$.

Comment: In general elliptical curves used in cryptography the generator $G$ does not generate all  possible points on the curve. So you need to multiply your point by co-factor which you forgot to mention

Comment: Also: the method uses "rejection sampling". It's hard to make a constant-time implementation of that, and some [state that might matter in the context](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-10.html#section-5-1) (ask why to them, not me; I've learned the hard way that when there's a requirement in a standard, the path of least resistance is to comply when possible, even if the rationale is unstated, lost, and the requirement demonstrably not useful in the situation at hand).

Answer (score 1):

The procedure that Mike Kaye suggested works; the other method would be to select a random value, and then use a [Hash-to-Curve](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve/) method to translate that random value to a point; they have been designed so that the order of that generated point is unknown.

Comment: There's room for expanding the answer on Hash-to-Curve. I find it nontrivial to extract the method(s) from the linked draft RFC. Also, the RFC "first hashes the input byte string to produce a uniformly random byte string", which silently assumes the input varies and is not handpicked, something I haven't found stated nearby, thus I'm not taking for granted that the rest if airtight.