# Random Generation a Valid Scalar on the Chosen Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

My implementation requires me to generate randomly a valid scalar on the curve. As far as I understand it is not a random number generation but more complicated thing.

I have to generate such scalars on the server and the client side according following scheme:

Client:

X = x × G + w0 × M

where

- x - generated scalar!
- G - curve base point
- w0 - a number represented by 32-byte array
- M - constant point on the curve
- X - resulted point

Server:

Y = y × G + w0 × N

where

- y - generated scalar!
- G - curve base point
- w0 - a number represented by 32-byte array
- N - constant point on the curve
- Y - resulted point

Then client and server exchanges X and Y points.

And calculate point Z as follows:

- Client: Z = x × (Y − w0 × N)
- Server: Z = y × (X − w0 × M)

Question#1: what the mechanism is for valid scalar random generation on the curve?

Question#2: what is the math operation behind points subtraction?

Comment: For random point generation: [Generating a random point on an elliptic curve over a finite field](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68603/18298) and point addition and negative is [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66288/18298)

Answer (score 1):

Scalars are not "on the curve". Scalars are just positive integers (including zero) less than the group order $\ell$ of the curve generator. E.g. for the Ed25519 curve, the group order $\ell$ is $2^{252} + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493$.

To generate an unbiased random scalar, use "rejection sampling". This means to use a mechanism to securely generate a uniformly random integer within a range that is at least as large as $\ell$, and accept it only if it is less than $\ell$.

All scalar operations, including addition, multiplication, and subtraction are done $mod\ \ell$. Division is achieved by finding something called the "[modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)".

Point operations, such as point subtraction, will be handled by your EC library. See [here](https://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/17/elliptic-curve-cryptography-a-gentle-introduction/) for more.